# How to close a PopUp which appears through a NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, controller, navigation, popup

I am creating an app for iOS using xCode with Swift 4.2.
I have this PopUp which gives information about different topics and links to different websites.

The reason why I embedded a navigation controller is that if I manually add a "back" button the whole webview in my main viewcontroller I'm using reloads and that takes much time.

Anyhow, I want this PopUp to get closed. And I do not find any useful information on the internet about that.
It would be a great help if you could tell me how I close this popup by simply adding a "X" button to close it without reloading my webview.

Comment: are you present this popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dismiss a popup use:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can set it to an UIButton or any action.